# History.js - subdirectory urls with # not #./

Tags: single-page-application, pushstate, history.js

I'm building a single page application in a subdirectory of my site and have started using history.js for updating the url.

The HTML4 fallback with hashes by default includes the whole path after the hash - including the subdirectory. If I make these relative paths then it includes an ugly "/#./".

I'd like to know how I could achieve the following.

HTML5 url

mydomain/mysubdirectory/myhistoryjspath

HTML4 url

mydomain/mysubdirectory/#/myhistoryjspath

Any ideas?

Thanks